# How to set SublimeText to auto match brackets but neither quotes or parenthesis?

Tags: regex, autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I find the auto match behavior in sublime text 3 is not quite up to snuff when you're typing code and more importantly when you're going back to edit in real time it can add all kinds of parens or quotes you don't really need.

But it's pretty much always perfect at auto matching squirly brackets {} so that's still a very useful feature especially since I type a lot of them in a local markup language.

I know I can turn auto match off but I don't want to turn off the behavior entirely, just modify it to not auto match "" or ().

Does anyone know the command to put in the user settings for this?

Here's the steps I've done to try to resolve this:

```
find ~/ -name "Sublime Text"
find ~/ -name "BracketHighlighter"
```

Both return nothing. So I can't find this 'BracketHighlighter.sublime-settings'

Instead of looking for it on the hard drive, I accessed it via the built in menus in Sublime Text via:

- Preferences ->
- Package Settings ->
- Bracket Highlighter ->
- Bracket Settings - User

This last menu option opens a file called "~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/bh_core.sublime-settings. In there I've pasted the code from AGS' answer and toggled:

```
"auto_match_enabled" : true,
"auto_match_enabled" : false,
```

I have tried both auto match settings while the code has been saved to the bh_core.sublime-settings file. Neither option produces the result as expected. With auto match on, braces, brackets, and quotes are matched. With auto match off, nothing is matched. But I have confirmed the module is on and active as brackets are getting highlighted when selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I know I can turn auto match off but I don't want to turn off the behavior entirely, just modify it to not auto match "" or ()*

You could install and customize the settings of the [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter) package.

Disable the system auto-matching:

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`

```
"auto_match_enabled": true,
```

Then edit:

OS X file location:

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/BracketHighlighter.sublime-settings`

```
{
            "name": "round",
            "open": "(\\()",
            "close": "(\\))",
            "style": "round",
            "scope_exclude_exceptions": ["string.other.math.block.environment.latex"],
            "scope_exclude": ["string", "comment"],
            "language_filter": "blacklist",
            "language_list": ["Plain text"],
            "find_in_sub_search": "true",
            "ignore_string_escape": true,
            "enabled": true
        },
 {
            "name": "double_quote",
            "open": "(\")",
            "close": "(\")",
            "style": "double_quote",
            "scopes": ["string"],
            "language_filter": "blacklist",
            "language_list": ["Plain text"],
            "sub_bracket_search": "true",
            "enabled": true
        },
```

Comment: I'm close but it's giving me a parsing error when I save it to the file @AGS

I went to Preferences -> Package Settings -> Bracket Highlighter -> Bracket Settings - User to input the settings. I

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 12.04. Unfortunately 'find ~/ -name "Sublime Text" returns nothing. And to disable matching you need "auto_match_enabled": false but you have it set to true which is conflicting. Finally, when fixing your code by wrapping it in square brackets the functionality didn't work with auto match set to true or false after adding it to the user settings for Bracket Highlighter via the preferences menu as I explained above.

Comment: @advocate, my code snippet was to show you where to look within the `sublime-settings` files.  I indicated in my post that these fields need to be set to `false`. I'm sorry but I am having trouble understanding what you have done and what is/is not working based upon your comments.

Comment: thanks for the quick followup @AGS. I've edited my original question. I couldn't properly explain in the comments without extensive markup help.

Comment: BracketHighlighter does not seem to do any auto-matching, and I think this is a limitation of sublime plugins.  I tried doing the aforementioned settings in both Sublime Text 2/3; none worked.  Docs make no mention of auto-matching, and neither does the code.  This answer was accepted, but there was no followup on if or how it was working.

Comment: I second @ShaunLebron. I needed to use `[` extensively as a escape character and it's incredibly annoying when `[]` pops up instead. Manually managing the deletion of all the spawned `]` is driving me nuts. Having to lose the auto-pairing functionality of  `(`, `{`, `'`, and `"` with `"auto_match_enabled": false` is equally unacceptable. I couldn't coerce BracketHighlighter into disabling the pairing for  `[` either. I assume this is not one of the achievable things with this plugin.